# Background image won't appear

Tags: css

My background image won't show. I provided a photo of my directory just in the case below
[image directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWrvo.png)[directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQSGC.png)

```
 /*Moto G4, Galaxy S5*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .game {
    width: 360px;
    height: 640px;
    background-image: url(img/mario.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried your styles and mirrored your file structure and have not been able to reproduce your problem. What size device/viewport are you using? Also, are you getting any errors on your browser's dev tools console? Does it work if you remove the media query?

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Just add ' ' in `background-image: url('img/mario.jpg');`

```
 /*Moto G4, Galaxy S5*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .game {
    width: 360px;
    height: 640px;
    background-image: url('img/mario.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: "Quotes are required if the URL includes parentheses, whitespace, or quotes, unless these characters are escaped, or if the address includes control characters above 0x7e. " see [link]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url() for example. i.e. in this case they are not required.